# What is the use of the "of" keyword in Swift?

Tags: swift

Example:

func student(**of** name: String) -> String {

.
.
.

}

Comment: It’s not a keyword. It has the same status as `student`.

Comment: For your reference : [Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, "of" is the label for the argument called "name".

If you were to call this function, it would be

```
student(of: "Mathematics")
```

However inside the student function, you would get it's value with "name"

```
func student(of name: String) -> String {

    print(name)

    // TODO: Do something and return

}
```

Just a suggestion, IMHO "of" is not very descriptive of what the function does or what "of" represents (is "of" an id? The name of the student?).

Comment: This would return "Something" regardless of what parameter you feed it.

Comment: @Adrian Edited the answer for clarity, the `return "Something"` was a placeholder since the original question only showed the method signature without the implementation.

Answer (score 3):

In that context, it's merely part of a method signature. To my knowledge, `of` is not a word that's used in Swift. To utilize that method, you'd type:

`student(of: "<Student's name here>")` and it would return a string.

If you omitted `of` from the signature above (`func student(name: String) -> String`), the method would be called as follows:

`student(name: "Student's name here")`

Lastly, if you changed the signature to put an underscore in front of the parameter, like so `func student(_ name: String) -> String`, you'd call the method as follows:

`student("Student's name here")`

Comment: @par Good call. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Swift has a concept of **external** as well as **internal** parameter name. **External** parameter names are used to make the function signature more readable where as **Internal** parameter names are used for usage inside the function.

**External** parameter names are optional. If only one parameter name is provided, that name is used as both **External** and **Internal**. An **External** parameter name for the first parameter is required. If at any stage, you don't want to specify an **External** parameter, you can replace it with `_`.

Consider the following example:

```
func myFunctionToPrintDetailsOfStudentWithFirstName(_ firstName: String, andLastName lastName: String, fromAddress: String)
```

Note that in this example, the first parameter has an **Internal** name only, the second parameter has both and the last one only has one. The function call would look like

```
myFunctionToPrintDetailsOfStudentWithFirstName("John", andLastName: "Doe", fromAddress: "My Country")
```

As you can see, the first parameter is passed without a parameter name, the second parameter is passed using the **External** name and the last parameter is passed using the only parameter name. This makes the function call more readable.

**Note:**

Within the function declaration, the first parameter would be accessed by `firstName`, the second by `lastName` and the last one by `fromAddress`

Hope this clarifies the differences for you